# GitBash - clone on a mac

Tags: git, git-bash

I'm trying to run the following command in GitBash on my Mac but it keeps giving the following error:

Fatal: repository path does not exist.

When I run this on a windows machine it works great, but I need to run it on my Mac :(

Does anyone have any ideas to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`Fatal: repository path does not exist.` means that you are trying to run `git` commands in a directory without a repository, you need to `git clone` to get a repo or `git init` to create one, or `cd` to a already checked out repo directory.

All repository files are in the `.git` directory in the root of the project directory. You are probably lacking one.